# Store external API token with Node

Tags: node.js, reactjs, token

I'm building a small app with Node (server) and React (front). I make API calls to an external application and the token has to be refreshed often. For now, I've tried two options but they are not optimal :

- First I get the Token on React parent component, save it in local storage then pass it to to the child component which will pass it to the server which will handle the call. The problem is that the asynchronous nature of React creates some problems.
- Each time I call the API, I generate a new token. The problem is that I could have a lot of API calls.

What would you recommend me?

Thanks

Comment: Your architecture is something like this: client -> backend -> external API? Client request token from the API and that request the external API, correct?

Comment: Yes. client in react make a call to the node server and then the server call the api, get the info et give it back to the client

Comment: You are updating the token and saving it in localStorage. You can add an event listener for storage event and then make api calls.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/storage_event

Comment: @Inder Isn't that dangerous to store it using localStorage ?

Comment: It is. But you mentioned that you're saving the token in localStorage.

Comment: token are always stored in localStorage and they can be dangerous based on the security you have on the backend systems.

Comment: Yes indeed I stored it in local storage but I want to get rid of that option because of security reasons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a layer in the API to make sure that you don't request a new token until it expires or you don't have the token and ofcourse you need to make an API call only when you don't have token in local storage.

So, there are two places you need to write a logic to make sure if you need token or its already there.

1. Client-side: before making the API call check if token exist for the user. If it is not present, request the token from Node.js API.
2. Backend: You need to keep the token in DB or cache(in-memory db) with the client id or any unique id. Saving in DB can be good option even if your server restarted you have track of all the active tokens.

Before making the request to the external API check if you already have a token with you.

The problem might be you are missing one of these steps or both and thats why you are getting new token everytime.